# Getting this error while providing build path in Jenkins. I am configuring build deployment on Hockey app using Jenkins! How to resolve the issue?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, hockeyapp

Getting this error while providing build path in Jenkins. I am configuring build deployment on Hockey app using Jenkins! How to resolve the issue?

```
Started by user Shrey Parashar
Building in workspace C:\Users\admin\.jenkins\workspace\HotelAndroidApp
Uploading to HockeyApp...
java.io.IOException: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'D:/Original_Native_Script_Hotel_App_Code/hotel-mobile-app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/HotelSearch**/*.apk'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax
    at hudson.FilePath.glob(FilePath.java:1868)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$2400(FilePath.java:209)
    at hudson.FilePath$23.invoke(FilePath.java:1848)
    at hudson.FilePath$23.invoke(FilePath.java:1845)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1047)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1025)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1845)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1829)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1814)
    at hockeyapp.HockeyappRecorder.performForApplication(HockeyappRecorder.java:225)
    at hockeyapp.HockeyappRecorder.perform(HockeyappRecorder.java:203)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1819)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Upload to HockeyApp' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is explanatory enough. The format of the path is not acceptable.

Please fix the path to top level directory where your apk files are located.

Ex:

server.src= D:/Original_Native_Script_Hotel_App_Code/hotel-mobile-app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/HotelSearch/
dir="${server.src}"

include name="**/*.apk"/>

Comment: No, it is not working. It says
Started by user Shrey Parashar
Building in workspace C:\Users\admin\.jenkins\workspace\HotelAndroidApp
Uploading to HockeyApp...
No IPA/APK found to upload in: server.src= D:/Original_Native_Script_Hotel_App_Code/hotel-mobile-app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/HotelSearch/ dir="${server.src}"  include name="**/*.apk"/>
Build step 'Upload to HockeyApp' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: This is below my actual path where my apk is
D:\Original_Native_Script_Hotel_App_Code\hotel-mobile-app\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\HotelSearch.apk

How to write this above path in ant glob format or which format I used to put in  post-build action (Jenkins) in App file path.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give absolute path give relative path and it should work as mentioned here 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/job-dsl-plugin/1ybmBMm96-A